# How to identify which svn plugin is installed in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, eclipse-kepler

I have eclipse Kepler as IDE and I have installed svn plugin a long ago it could be either subclipse or subversion. I can't remember which one I installed. Is there a way easy to verify which plugin is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Help > About Eclipse dialog (Eclipse > About Eclipse on Macs).

Click the `Installation Details` button.

The `Installed Software` tab will contain several entries for Subversive if that is what you have installed (and something different for Subclipse - I'm not sure what).

Comment: Thank you! I found it. It is subversive.